# Autoclick where is mouse position with javascript

Tags: javascript, click, position, mouse

I have search this kind of post and i didnt find anything.

So my question is :

Is it possible after a time make an auto click on current position mouse?

Example: If mouse is over link blablaba.com click on link or mouse over is over another link so click on that link.

Sorry for my English.

Thank you.

I want to add code on my website, and after a time do autoclick on current position of mouse.

Comment: You might consider ginving a more explicit information. You don't even specify the operating system or what language/interface you are using.

Comment: JAvascript! I want to add code on my website, and after a time do autoclick on curent position of mouse.

Comment: Update your post, as this is what people are reading.

Comment: You may be need this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604118/possible-to-get-the-current-mouse-coords-with-javascript   Combined with settimeout() function

Comment: I had tried with this and it`s not working.

Comment: You should  told that you want to click over an iframe. It is impossible, because you have same domain policy rules for JS.

Answer (score 0):

You have this all wrong. Events like "click" are used to trigger function calls. You don't need to trigger the event manually, just call the functions that were about to be called if someone triggered it.

Specifically, if you want the user to land on a new page(that happens when the user clicks a link) you can use [redirects](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php)

Comment: Redirect didnt resolve my problem. I have a iframe and i want after a specified time to autoclick inside that iframe.