# Draggable in circle

Tags: jquery, draggable

I've created a draggable that moves in a circle:

```
var wskaznik = document.getElementById("wskaznik");
var pozycja_kamery_pole = document.getElementById("pozycja_kamery");
var pozycja_kamery = {
szerokosc: pozycja_kamery_pole.offsetWidth,
wysokosc: pozycja_kamery_pole.offsetHeight,
gora: pozycja_kamery_pole.offsetTop,
lewo: pozycja_kamery_pole.offsetLeft
};
pozycja_kamery.srodek = [pozycja_kamery.lewo + pozycja_kamery.szerokosc / 2,     pozycja_kamery.gora + pozycja_kamery.wysokosc / 2];
pozycja_kamery.promien = (pozycja_kamery.szerokosc / 2) -10;

function kolo(x, y) {
var odst = odstep([x, y], [65,65]);
if (odst <= pozycja_kamery.promien) {
    return {x: x, y: y};
} 
else {
    x = x - 65;
    y = y - 65;
    var radians = Math.atan2(y, x)
       return {
           x: Math.cos(radians) * canvas.radius + 65,
           y: Math.sin(radians) * canvas.radius + 65
       }
    } 
}
function odstep(pkt1, pkt2) {
var x1 = pkt1[0],
    y1 = pkt1[1],
    x2 = pkt2[0],
    y2 = pkt2[1];
return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2));
}
```

But it's not a smooth movement. How to fix it? Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/draqo/DAyrH/

I've followed this:
    http://jsfiddle.net/7Asn6/

Comment: canvas is not defined change it to pozycja_kamery.promien [http://jsfiddle.net/DAyrH/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/DAyrH/1/)

Comment: see my answer you also need to remove the containment or the movement will stop on some borders of the parent div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change canvas.radius for pozycja_kamery.promien in your function kolo like this

```
function kolo(x, y) {
var odst = odstep([x, y], [65,65]);
if (odst <= pozycja_kamery.promien) {
    return {x: x, y: y};
} 
else {
    x = x - 65;
    y = y - 65;
    var radians = Math.atan2(y, x)
       return {//pozycja_kamery.promien is ($("#pozycja_kamery").width()/2)-10
           x: Math.cos(radians) * pozycja_kamery.promien + 65,
           y: Math.sin(radians) * pozycja_kamery.promien + 65
       }
    } 
}
```

you can remove the containment: "#pozycja_kamery" in $("#wskaznik").draggable
http://jsfiddle.net/DAyrH/2/

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine as long as the cursor is within the circle...maybe you need some mouse tracking - e.g. [Possible to get the current mouse coords with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604118/possible-to-get-the-current-mouse-coords-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add code which will continue to update the position of the dot after the mouse leaves the circle.  Currently it seems that you only update the position when the mouse is clicked and above the dot, you should set some variable on a mousedown above the dot and update the position until a mouseup event.

Something like this:

```
var isClicked = false;

window.onmouseup = function() {isClicked=false;}
getElementById("wskaznik").onmousedown=function() {isClicked = true;}

function updateCircle() {
    if (isClicked) {
        // update the position
        // if the mouse is within the boundary circle set to those coordinates.
        // if not set it to the nearest point on the boundary circle

    }
}
```